# Difference between Zero Knowledge Range Proof (ZKRP), Zero Knowledge Set Membership (ZKSM) protocols and ZKP

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Like to know the difference between Zero Knowledge Range Proof (ZKRP), Zero Knowledge Set Membership (ZKSM) protocols and ZKP?

Nathan Aw

Comment: ZKRP and ZKSM are zero-knowledge proofs for specific statements. In a zero-knowledge range proof, for example, the prover generates a proof for an assertion like $v\in [0, 2^n]$ for some secret value $v$.

Comment: thanks! how are these assertions generated?

Comment: The proof generation is highly non-trivial. For details you can see, e.g., the Bulletproofs paper.